# Exclude Models from being saved with Breeze

Tags: breeze

I have EntityA which has a navigation property to EntityB. In the frontend it's possible to create a new EntityA and append it to EntityB. If I now try to save the new created EntityA, Breeze also want's to save the changes on EntityB (containing the new ID of the newly created EntityA). Is it somehow possible to avoid having EntityB, because in this specific use case it should be possible to append new entities to EntityB, but these should not be saved back (and also not be reported as pending changes)?

I see the possibility with using two EntityManagers, but this would mean that I can no longer have navigation properties between the two types.

Comment: Is that a one to one relationship?

Comment: Yes, EntitiyB has one or zero EntityA, EntityA has always an EntityB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal is asking an important question: **are Entity A and Entity B related one-to-one**? More to the point are they related one-to-one **such that A depends on B** (i.e. A is a child of B)?

A typical relationship of this sort is the "extension" entity. Consider "Order" and "OrderExtension".  "OrderExtension" is a bolt-on type with optional fields that "extend" the core order data. An order can have zero or one "OrderExtension" records.

`Order` is the parent in this example; it SHOULD NOT have a FK reference to the `OrderExtension`.  The `OrderExtension` is the child and it SHOULD HAVE a required `OrderID` FK field. The parent `Order` can exist without a child, but the child `OrderExtension` cannot exist w/o the parent.

**At least that's how I think it should be.**  I've often seen folks turn this around. They give the `Order` an `OrderExtensionID` FK field which is optional. The `OrderExtension` has no backpointer to the `Order`.

The weakness of this design is that it allows you to create multiple orphaned `OrderExtension` entities that don't belong to anything ... and you'll rarely know they are there.

I'm betting that's your situation. I'm betting that Entity B is like `OrderExtension` and Entity A is like `Order`.  When you created the `OrderExtension` (B) and associated it with an `Order` (A), Breeze tried to maintain that relationship for you by updating the `Order.OrderExtensionID` property. That puts `Order` (A) in a modified state.

**DO not proceed until you've figured this out**. While Jeremy is correct that you *can save one entity* by cherry picking the pending changes - you can save B without saving A -, you risk breaking the integrity of your data!

From a modeling perspective **you've made Entity A dependent on Entity B**. If you don't save A at the same time you save B, there will be no way for someone using the database to know that the two are related.

Next time you query for either of them, neither you nor Breeze will know they are related. You will be unable to navigate between A and B. I'm pretty sure that's not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array containing the entities you wish to save to the saveChanges method to restrict which entities are saved.

**From the [breeze docs](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges):**

> **saveChanges ( [entities]  [saveOptions]  [callback]  [errorCallback] ) async**
>
> Saves either a list of specified entities or all changed entities
>   within this EntityManager. If there are no changes to any of the
>   entities specified then there will be no server side call made but a
>   valid 'empty' saveResult will still be returned.
>
> Parameters:
>
> [entities] Array of Entity optional The list of entities to save.
>   Every entity in that list will be sent to the server, whether changed
>   or unchanged, as long as it is attached to this EntityManager. If this
>   parameter is omitted, null or empty (the usual case), every entity
>   with pending changes in this EntityManager will be saved.